# Installing netcdf c++ interface on 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am using a code which employs the modern netCDF c++ interface (netcdf namespace, include file is called just netcdf without `.h` or similar, ncFile class, etc) and have just switched to 12.04.1.

I installed netCDF and `libnetcdf6` with `apt-get`, but I still get the "old" headers in `/usr/local/include` (netcdf.h, netcdfcpp.h, etc).

In Ubuntu, the library version for netCDF is `4.1.1`, while at my own computer with Mac Os X (where I have the right netCDF include file) the version is `4.2.1.1`.

I cannot modify the source code I am using. I would like to know if there is a way to upgrade the netCDF library on Ubuntu to support the modern c++ interface, or, if I have to manually compile it, if you think that using `src2pkg` is a good idea. This is my first experience with Ubuntu.

Comment: And later of the installation of netcdf, what should I do in order to check if my installation has been successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal and run these commands:

```
wget http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/ftp/netcdf-4.2.1.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf netcdf-4.2.1.1.tar.gz
cd netcdf-4.2.1.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

For more information, in the `netcdf-4.2.1.1` directory you will have a README file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will do that. I though there was a more "ubuntu-like" way to do that rather than compiling from sources. It will bring me memories from when I was using Slackware and compiling from source.

Comment: I just want to add that to get the modern c++ interface I am looking for, I need to install the tarball from `http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/ftp/netcdf-cxx4-4.2.tar.gz`